# AngularJS Ng-model has no data from form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form class="" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="MailingListController">
        <input class="form-element large" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="emailaddress">
        <input class="form-submit button large bkg-charcoal bkg-hover-pink color-white color-hover-white" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

```
<script>
    angular.module('ComingSoon', [])
        .controller('MailingListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        console.log("Working");
        $scope.submit = function() {
            console.log($scope.emailaddress);
        };
        }]);
</script>
```

I have tried to submit this form and the logs is showing there is nothing inside $scope.emailaddress. I have followed the documentation from angular website but it still doesn't work. Where isit that i am doing it wrongly?

Comment: it seems to work actually, see here: https://jsbin.com/tawero/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Works fine? [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fC1l5cekyTrZXlX5XkMt?p=preview)

Comment: You have a problem in other section of code

Answer (score 0):

Controller Binding to the view May gone wrong .  you can take a look
 here in the following plnkr

html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ComingSoon">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>



<body ng-controller="MailingListController">

  <form class="" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input class="form-element large" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="emailaddress">
    <input class="form-submit button large bkg-charcoal bkg-hover-pink color-white color-hover-white" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>


</body>


</html>
```

controller :-

```
 angular.module('ComingSoon', [])
        .controller('MailingListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        console.log("Working");
        $scope.submit = function() {
            console.log($scope.emailaddress);
        };
        }]);
```

Check you console while doing !!

https://plnkr.co/edit/B7aJhGKhXin1tsldljpz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

hi it is working for me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('ComingSoon', [])
        .controller('MailingListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            console.log("Working");
            $scope.submit = function () {
                console.log($scope.emailaddress);
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ComingSoon">
    <form class="" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="MailingListController">
        <input class="form-element large" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="emailaddress">
        <input class="form-submit button large bkg-charcoal bkg-hover-pink color-white color-hover-white" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```